# change openstreetmap TYP in an android app?

Tags: openstreetmap

I use an OSM map in an android application using the osmdroid package and it works fine. The only thing I want to change is the visual appearance of the map to a typ, which is called "outdoor" style. I tried all the possibilities given in the setTileSource()-Function, but no map displays the map like in the piicture below. Is there a simple way to set a parameter somewhere to get the desired appearance of the map? I have seen some app's using this appearance. Thanks!

```
    mv.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
```

[this is what I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cl8E.jpg)

Comment: Where is this screenshot from? First you have to identify which tile server is using this style. I've never seen it before, it's not among the "usual" OSM styles.

Comment: Absolutely right, I have not found it too in the list, which provides the TileSourceFactory. 
When I was searching in the web to find information about it I found only a description in german language for a so-called "TYP" of the appearance for openstreetmaps, but I did not understand how to use it in Android.
The screenshot is taken from this site : http://freizeitkarte-osm.de/garmin/de/design.html!

Comment: This *typ*-file is soley for Garmin. The appearance of OSM tiles is defined by the *style*. Yet, it is irrelevant for you since you probably don't want to render your own tiles. Instead you want to use a certain tile server. Here is a list of various available tile servers: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles. Make sure to read the usage policy / terms of use for the tile server you are choosing.

Comment: thank you very much, scai! I will check the site and the policies.